# how to compare a date field to the current date in field access rule [odoo 10]

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

My record can only be modified before a given date (in a field).

I thought about using record rules but can't compare a date field to the current date in access rule.

Any way to do the comparison or another way to achieve this?

```
<record id="my_rule_date_foo" model="ir.rule">
<field name="name">foo bar</field>
<field name="model_id" ref="model_my_foo"/>
<field name="domain_force">
    [('many2one_field.the_limit_date','&ge;', 'what_to_put_here_?')]
</field>
<field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_peff'))]"/>
<field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
<field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
<field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
<field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
```

Comment: A screenshot may be helpful to answer @Jean Pernier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `context_today()` or `datetime` in the `domain_force`:

```
# Should be the best choice, considers user timezone
[('many2one_field.the_limit_date','&gt;=', context_today())]

# If context_today() doesn't work for some reason, you can use datetime
[('many2one_field.the_limit_date','&gt;=', datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]
```

Here's [the `context_today` method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L1491) from core and a [relevant gist for reference](https://gist.github.com/ilyasProgrammer/b2c6e78716c0e5286caa7c1184f82d0d).